# cellForRowAtIndexPath not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView in my application and when a user taps on that cell, I need it to go to another view controller that gives more details about the cell they clicked on. When I try to get the cellForRowAtIndexPath by using

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

    }
```

Nothing is printed to the console so I cant pass that data to another view controller through a segue without knowing that. Is there a reason this would not work?

I am getting the information though this array: `var postsArray = [PFObject]()` and the table is populated using `return postsArray.count`
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I may be overlooking it but I am not sure why this would not work as it has worked in other applications of mine.

I have imported delegates as well and have also called `table.delegate = self` to my viewDidLoad method.

```
class Profile: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
```

The full code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/26frZGpa

Comment: thats a tableview delegate method. did you set your tableview's delegate to be an instance of class that implements that method? For example, `tableView.delegate = self` if self also owns the tableview

Comment: Yes I did Will. Sorry, I just added that part to the question.

Comment: See my comment edit. Have you done that yet? Just declaring Profile to be a UITableViewDelegate allows it to be a tableView's delegate, but until you actually set your instance of Profile to be the delegate for that specific tableview, it won't receive callbacks for that tableview

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. This is called in the viewDidLoad function in my application.

Comment: Does the table view display anything?

Comment: Can you post the table view's declaration and its creation (initialization)?

Comment: Yes the table displays what I need it to, it is just not getting the index Path when I call it for some reason.

Comment: I added a pastebin of the whole code.

Comment: `tableView.delegate = self` as suggested in the very first comment is missing, that's the reason why the delegate method is not called. You can connect the delegate also in Interface Builder. And it's highly recommended to cache the images rather than reload them multiple times in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on how I can do that (Cache the images)?

Comment: Search google for *asynchronous UITableViewCell content* or similar keywords. There are many suggestions.

Comment: I would love to give you credit for this answer if youd like to post it below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
tableView.delegate = self
```

as suggested in the very first comment is missing, that's the reason why the delegate method is not called. You can connect the delegate also in Interface Builder.

In your case to perform the segue it's more convenient to connect the segue to the table view cell rather than to the view controller.

The major benefit is that the table view cell is passed as the `sender` parameter in `prepareForSegue` and you can get the index path easily with

```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
      let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell)!
  }
```

Comment: Could we start a chat for a second? I have one more question.

Comment: I'm afraid no, I got to go.

Comment: Is there anyway I can reach you for a future question? I'm sure it is a simple answer just not sure about something.